# How can I read the HTML inside a XML tag?

Tags: c#, html, .net, xml, xmldocument

I have a XML that return, at some point, this:

```
<TESTO>
    <img src="../path/image.jpg" alt="" />
</TESTO>
```

well, if I do:

```c#
string TESTO = m_oNode.SelectSingleNode("TESTO").InnerText;
```

TESTO will be "empty". Why? How can I read the whole text? With other tag without HTML tag all works perfectly...

I use `XmlDocument`

## EDIT - code that create an Exception with InnerXml():

```
<TESTO>
    <table style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="700"><a href="http://www.my.it/"><img src="/testata.jpg" alt="mycaf.it" width="700" height="333" border="0" /></a></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #f5f5f5;" align="center" bgcolor="#f5f5f5"><br />
    <p style="color: #ee2e24; font-style: italic; font-size: 25px; font-family: Arial;">portale<br /> </p>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</TESTO>
```

Comment: is that C#? what is `m_oNode`?

Comment: Do you use XDocument to read the xml? 
if yes try:
m_oNode.Element("TESTO").Value

Comment: @markzzz Your XML is not a valid XML file. You can't load it with _XmlDocument_.

Comment: Because there is no DOCTYPE? I get it from a external source, so I can't edit it! How can I do?

Comment: @markzzz because of _&ndsp;_

Comment: Well. So how can I fix it?

Comment: I fixed adding the doctype at the string. Not a great solution, but the only I guess. Also, I noticed that w3 have put a limiter on downloading DTD, which cause XmlDocument be soo slow. So, I've downloaded files and cache them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InnerText` gets only the Text (for mixed content or text content). Use `InnerXml` instead.

Example:

```
<A>
    Some text in mixed content
    <B>OnlyText</B>
</A
```

Gives the result:

- `InnerText = "Some text in mixed content\r\nOnlyText"`
- `InnerXml = "Some text in mixed content\r\n<B>OnlyText</B>";`

Comment: he's using `XmlDocument`, so `InnerXml` will do.

Comment: @w0lf Thanks for the precision. I am not really used to _XmlDocument_. Only to _XDocument_ and _HtmlDocument_.

Comment: you're not missing much. :)

Comment: I have a problem with this! The XML I get is without DOCTYPE. So when I read line with "&nbsp;" for example, I got a Try Catch `reference entity not decleared : "nbsp"`

Comment: I don't parse HTML, I don't need it! I just get it and store into a string variable. But seems it create this exception?

Comment: @markzzz Can you upload the file you are having this problem with?

Comment: Check the update answer! Please note: the XML I get doesn't have DOCTYPE

Answer (score 0):

To read the content of an html element you have to use yourElement.innerXml instead of yourElement.InnerText

Per leggere il contenuto di un elemento html devi usare yourElement.innerXml al posto di yourElement.InnerText :)